# XML Deserilization - where attribute acts a property of the class

Tags: c#, xml, deserialization, xml-deserialization

I have an XML in below format

`<data><element id='abc.pqr'>1</element><element id='abc.xyz'>2</element></data>`

I want to deserilize it in a class below:

```
class data
{
    public string pqr {get;set;}
    public string xyz {get;set;}
}
```

where when deserilized pqr and xyz will hold value 1 and 2 respectively.

I tried using XmlRoot and XmlAttribute attributes to map the class but then in that case I am getting a new class object every time and I am not able to assign value to the property.
What other approach I can take to solve this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't think this is possible without creating a custom deserializer.

Comment: Can you please elaborate on what this means: "I tried using XmlRoot and XmlAttribute attributes to map the class but then in that case I am getting a new class object every time and I am not able to assign value to the property"